# How do I disable pyflakes-vim for a particular file?

Tags: python, vim, pyflakes

I have some autogenerated python files that are extremely large (long mathematical equations). Vim slows to a crawl when I open them for editing because I have pyflakes-vim installed. I'd like to be able to disable pyflakes-vim only when I open these long files. Is there a simple way to do this, either before opening the file or even after? I do not want to turn off pyflakes-vim for all python files, just a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Could you define "extremely large"? I haven't seen that behaviour with 'flakes ever.

Comment: ~5000 lines and ~800K characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another solution which is handy: https://github.com/kevinw/pyflakes-vim/pull/47

This fork of pyflakes-vim, which has not been merged in yet, allows you to toggle pyflakes on or off.

Comment: It looks like pyflakes-vim is no longer been maintained. I've emailed the author, send a pull request, created an issue in the bug tracker but never got a response. Would you be interested in getting your changes merged properly in a newly maintained pyflakes-vim fork?

Answer (score 4):

PyFlakes won't run if `b:did_pyflakes_plugin` is defined when the plugin is loaded, but once it's loaded I don't think there's an easy way to disable it.

What I would do is give the auto-generated files a specific file name pattern (say *_auto.py) and then add to my .vimrc: `autocmd BufReadPre *_auto.py :let b:did_pyflakes_plugin=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [flake8](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8) - either as part of [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) or just [vim-flake8](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8) - then you can add `# noqa` at the end of a line to disable checking for that line. Also see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033727/how-do-i-get-pyflakes-to-ignore-a-statement).

Comment: Worked for me! Note: there must be a separation of 2 spaces between the last character in the code and the '#'.