# Ignoring single line marked as incorrect by Sublime CodeIntel

Tags: sublimetext2, code-intelligence

I'm using Sublime for a Python project.  I have a dictionary comprehension like so:

```
inv_map = {v:k for k, v in map.items()}
```

CodeIntel is marking this as an "invalid syntax" error, but this is correct and runs without trouble.

How can I tell CodeIntel to ignore this specific line?

Comment: Are your versions of Python the same?

Comment: I only have 2.7 installed, not using a virtualenv for this project.

Comment: Dict comprehensions were introduced in 2.7. What OS are you using?

Comment: Yep, and they work correctly on my version.  OSX.

Comment: And are you using the pre-installed Python or did you install it with Homebrew?

Comment: The pre-installed version.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary comprehension (feature you are using) is Python 2.7+.

```
    inv_map = {v:k for k, v in map.items()}
```

Internally SublimeLinter runs Python command line programs called pep8 (pep8 is a package name for [PEP-8 guideline checks](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and pyflakes. Due to architecture of SublimeLinter, running them is may be limited to Python 2.x targets, a Python version embedded by Sublime Text.

Relevant SublimeLinter source code here:

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/blob/master/sublimelinter/modules/python.py

The error in your question can come from pep8 or Pyflakes.

Pyflakes does not offer documentation how to make it ignore any lines. Probably not possible, as the suggestion in the answers of this question [How do I get Pyflakes to ignore a statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033727/how-do-i-get-pyflakes-to-ignore-a-statement) is not to use Pyflakes.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes

pep8 offers only global error and warning ignores, not on per-file or per-line basis.

http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#configuration

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions were backported to my version, 2.7.

Comment: @alex-bf Thanks a lot - I had missed the fact!

Comment: Please note that this has been fixed in Sublime Text 3 and new SublimeLinter package