# PEP8 – import not at top of file with sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

## Problem

PEP8 has a rule about putting imports at the top of a file:

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

However, in certain cases, I might want to do something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert("..", 0)

import my_module
```

In this case, the `pep8` command line utility flags my code:

> E402 module level import not at top of file

What is the best way to achieve PEP8 compliance with `sys.path` modifications?

## Why

I have this code because I'm following [the project structure](https://github.com/kennethreitz/samplemod) given in [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#structure-of-the-repository).

That guide suggests that I have a `my_module` folder, separate from a `tests` folder, both of which are in the same directory. If I want to access `my_module` from `tests`, I think I need to add `..` to the `sys.path`

Comment: Why don't you write a `setup.py` and actually *install* `my_module` for testing?

Comment: Because that's slightly less convenient. I suppose I *could* but I'd rather not.

Comment: For whom? If you ever want to actually *use* this project anywhere it's far and away the easiest way to get it up and running.

Comment: @jonrsharpe for me. This is more of a personal project for my use. I'll definitely use that if no other answers come up.

Comment: If you're not sharing it, why worry about following PEP-8 so closely?

Comment: From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): "However, know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment.". There are times when you have to break PEP8 compliance, and that is OK.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's a good habit to get into for future things that I will share. (I do see your point though, in that case I can use setup.py). I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Often I have multiple files with tests in a subdirectory `foo/tests` of my project, while the modules I'm testing are in `foo/src`. To run the tests from `foo/tests` without import errors I create a file `foo/tests/pathmagic.py` that looks like this;

```
"""Path hack to make tests work."""

import os
import sys

bp = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('.')).split(os.sep)
modpath = os.sep.join(bp + ['src'])
sys.path.insert(0, modpath)
```

In every test file, I then use

```
import pathmagic  # noqa
```

as the first import. The "noqa" comment prevents `pycodestyle`/`pep8` from complaining about an unused import.

Comment: This is cool, but this still have 'imported but unused [F401]' problem.

Comment: I guess creating a dummy function in that pathmagic module and calling it from the test module would solve that issue but I wish there was something cleaner...

Comment: @Chung-YenHung Keep in mind that pycodestyle/pep8 warnings are advisory rather than syntax errors or exceptions. You can choose to ignore them. I've updated my answer by adding a "noqa" comment after the import.

Comment: One huge disadvantage of this, is turning your tests into a package so ``pathmagic`` can be importable.  Most python test runners assume your tests are a collections of files not on ``sys.path``, and changing that can leads to issues, see how ``pytest`` deals with these issues https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules

Comment: @Meitham Although my answer mentions how I used this to run tests back then, the question is not about running tests. (I have since moved to pytest for my tests.) In other situation this mechanism is still useful.

Comment: @RolandSmith thanks for clarifying.  I've landed in a project where their test is based on your answer, and moving the project to pytest.

Comment: ```sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'src')))```

Answer (score 137):

If there are just a few imports, you can just ignore PEP8 on those `import` lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert("..", 0)
import my_module  # noqa: E402
```

Comment: I prefer to be more explicit, specifying the violated rule like `# noqa: E402` for example. ([source](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html#in-line-ignoring-errors))

Comment: @MaxGoodridge indeed! Edited response to add the rule.

Comment: in case you have more than one import from the same path, i'ts shorter to put `# noqa: E402` on the `sys.path.insert...` line

Answer (score 14):

There is another workaround.

```
import sys
... all your other imports...

sys.path.insert("..", 0)
try:
    import my_module
except:
    raise
```

Comment: I strongly believe this will not work. The reason being, there may be some modules imported under "... all your imports ..." which might require PYTHONPATH to be set first.

Comment: @darkdefender27 the idea is to put all imports that requires PYTHONPATH inside `try` body and everything else (that does not depend on it) up above.

Comment: or even simpler: `if 1: import module`

Answer (score 10):

This problem already has several solutions that work, but in the case that you have a number of non-initial imports, and don't want to annotate each with `# noqa: E402` (or use one of the other proposals), the following works for a whole block:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert("..", 0)

if True:  # noqa: E402
    import my_module_1
    import my_module_2
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I've just struggled with a similar question, and I think I found a slightly nicer solution than the accepted answer.

Create a `pathmagic` module that does the actual sys.path manipulation, but make the change within a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers):

```
"""Path hack to make tests work."""

import os
import sys

class context:
    def __enter__(self):
        bp = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('.')).split(os.sep)
        modpath = os.sep.join(bp + ['src'])
        sys.path.insert(0, modpath)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass
```

Then, in your test files (or wherever you need this), you do:

```
import pathmagic

with pathmagic.context():
    import my_module
    # ...
```

This way you don't get any complaints from flake8/pycodestyle, you don't need special comments, and the structure seems to make sense.

For extra neatness, consider actually reverting the path in the `__exit__` block, though this may cause problems with lazy imports (if you put the module code outside of the context), so maybe not worth the trouble.

---

**EDIT**: Just saw a much simpler trick in an [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12121404/7581): add `assert pathmagic` under your imports to avoid the `noqa` comment.

Comment: All this really accomplished is getting rid of the next for the special comment at the expense of requiring the use of a context manager—a somewhat nebulous tradeoff in my opinion. As for cleaning-up in the `__exit__` block, to really do it properly would require just removing the added path (if it's still there) because restoring the entire previous value to what it was when the context was entered would also undo any other changes that might have been made to it by other code (executed in the same context) for some reason.

Comment: @martineau indeed, it's a matter of taste. I may be a little biased against special comments, because my current code base contains a little too many comments for the myriad static analysis tools and editors that the various teams are using.
Also agreed on your second point.

Comment: Problematic if `pathmagic.context()` can be called an arbitrary number of times (e.g. if running all tests). Reverting is problematic, too: any import at a later time (e.g. done on demand) can fail.

Answer (score 4):

Did you already try the following:

```
import sys
from importlib import import_module

sys.path.insert("..", 0)

# import module
my_mod = import_module('my_module')

# get method or function from my_mod
my_method = getattr(my_mod , 'my_method')
```

Answer (score 3):

To comply with the pep8, you should include your project path to the python path in order to perform relative / absolute imports.

To do so, you can have a look at this answer: [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Comment: I don't want to make this directory accessible globally to all my Python scripts, because that could cause conflicts.

Comment: You can use the https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html package to use namespaces. If you think your solution is the best, you are not in obligation to follow the pep8. Pep8 is only advices and best practices, that don't mean you must follow every rule, everytime, everywhere.

Comment: PEP 8 actually says [A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)

Comment: if only I didn't need to fight flake8 in git hooks and CI

Answer (score 3):

Given that the path to be added is relative to the script, this can be solved by using relative path.

```
from ..mypath import mymodule 
from ..mypath.mysubfolder import anothermodule
```

Then do not need to use `sys.path.insert()` anymore. Lint stoped complaining.

Answer (score 0):

THE EASIEST SOLUTION: In the case of `pytest` would be to add the path in `conftest.py`. This ensures that package path is added before running any tests.