# How to set PATH before imports occur in a nice way?

Tags: python, windows, python-import, openslide

I have a Python script which uses [openslide-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openslide-python).

openslide-python requires that [OpenSlide binaries are in the DLL search path on Windows](http://openslide.org/docs/windows/).

I am planning to distribute my application in the future and I don't want that users download OpenSlide binaries and set PATH. So I am going to include OpenSlide binaries with my application.

The problem is that PATH has to be set before any imports from OpenSlide occur.

Currently I have the following code (simplified with *):

```
import os
from io import *

os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + os.sep + 'openslide' + os.pathsep + os.environ[
    'PATH']

from openslide import *
```

I realize that it doesn't correspond with PEP 8, because I have a module level import not at top of file.

Any ideas how to make it nicely?

Comment: Use `sys.path.append()`?

Comment: @TuwuhS It still has to occur before importing things from openslide, right? If yes, then it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes it does, why do you think it is a problem?

Comment: @TuwuhS As I understand, according to PEP 8 I have ho have something like:
`import os`
`from io import *`

`from openslide import *`

`sys.path.append('...')`

Comment: I see your point. This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/36829884/6102131 (edit: linking to the answer instead)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `my_path_helper.py`:

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + os.sep + 'openslide' + os.pathsep + os.environ[
    'PATH']
```

and put it into same directory as your script.
Now import it:

```
import os
from io import *

import my_path_helper

from openslide import *
```

This still violates PEP8 a bit because it imports your own module before the third party module `openslide`. But all imports are at the top of your script.