# How to stop python linter (VSCode) from switching importing order

Tags: visual-studio-code, pep8, linter

I am currently using the default python linter in VSCode. However, the linter (*Format Document*) keeps changing the importing order of modules like below. Since the module (`project_settings.py`) is in the parent directory of the current script(`preprocess.py`), I believe I have to add the system path before importing (following [this_01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)).

Am I not following correct [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) rules? (following [this_02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827962/pep8-import-not-at-top-of-file-with-sys-path)) How can I import the modules in a different directory while linter not changing the importing order? Do I need to put some kind of ignore rules for the linter?

**Inside `preprocess.py`**

(Before Formatter)

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './scripts/')
from project_settings import *
```

(After Formatter)

```
from project_settings import *
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './scripts/')
```

**Project Structure**

```
root
└── scripts
    ├── data-preparation
    │   └── **preprocess.py**
    ├── ...
    ├── main.py
    ├── project_settings.py
    └── utils.py
```

---

p.s. I still want to use the Python linter, but want to use it correctly so that  the linter won't change the importing order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure this answers your question but you could disable lint on Vscode in the JSON settings.

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false
}
```