# What does '# noqa' mean in Python comments?

Tags: python, comments, terminology, code-analysis, pep8

While searching through a Python project, I found a few lines commented with `# noqa`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\dev')
import some_module   # noqa
```

What does `noqa` mean in Python? Is it specific to Python only?

Comment: `noqa` most likely stands for `no quality assurance`. It tells code-analysis software to ignore warnings.

Comment: Related: [How do I get Pyflakes to ignore a statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5033727/3357935)

Comment: In my head it always reads as "no questions asked"

Answer (score 424, accepted):

Adding `# noqa` to a line indicates that the linter (a program that automatically checks code quality) should not check this line. Any warnings that code may have generated will be ignored.

That line may have something that "looks bad" to the linter, but the developer understands and intends it to be there for some reason.

For more information, see the [Flake8 documentation for Selecting and Ignoring Violations](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html#in-line-ignoring-errors).

Comment: for python linters, it is this statement usually but for other linters it can be different, i.e. javascript w/ jshint is: `// jshint ignore:line` (http://jshint.com/docs/)

Comment: It works in PyCharm too.  Short form generic `# noqa`. Or long form specific `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` for example.

Comment: Note that for pycodestyle/pep8 `# nopep8` can also be used which is a little clearer, imo.

Answer (score 151):

## noqa = NO-QA (NO Quality Assurance)

It's generally used in Python code to ignore [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) warnings.

Lines with `#noqa` at the end will be ignored by linter programs and won't raise any warnings.

Answer (score 123):

You know what? Even Guido van Rossum (the creator of Python) [asked this question before](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/476) :D

[A bit **Etymology** of `# noqa`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/476#issuecomment-179553820):

> It used to be "nopep8" but when Flake8 and Pep8 wanted a common
>   qualifier @florentx suggested "NoQA" as in "No Quality Assurance"
>   (iirc) and it stuck.

[Some basic **usages** of `# noqa`](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/blob/master/README.rst) (with [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/index.html)):

- `# flake8: noqa`: *files* that contain *this line* are skipped
- *lines* that contain a `# noqa` comment *at the end*: will not issue warnings
- `# noqa: <error>`, e.g., `# noqa: E234` *at the end*: ignore *specific errors* on a line

  - multiple error codes can be given, separated by comma
  - the colon before the list of codes is required

Comment: this is definitively the best answer! academic, historical, practical, simple.

Comment: @d34n5 this is definitely the best comment! comprehensive, lyrical, monolexemic, simple.

Answer (score 31):

Came here after finding a # noqa directive in a library that I was working with. Having never heard of it, I naturally arrived here after searching on Google. The answers provided here are adequate but I wanted to provide some further elaboration for those that may be curious (I certainly was)

- `# noqa` has evolved from the `# nopep8` syntax used in previous
  releases of flake8
- `# noqa` is supported by IDEs, like PyCharm, for use with their
  built-in code inspection tools.
- `# noqa` can be used as a pre-commit directive, such that prior to new
  commits an inspection process must complete
- `# noqa` can be used to ignore all warnings or given specific warnings
  to ignore. For example, `# noqa: F401` will ignore an unused
  imported module warning.

As an example, consider the following code:

```
import os

print("Hello, world!")
```

This code imports the `os` module but doesn't use it. If one wanted to use the `# noqa` tool to suppress a PEP8 warning, it could be written as such:

```
import os  # noqa

print("Hello, world!")
```

This will ignore *all* warnings. However, if one were only to want to ignore a specific warning (PEP8 F401 imported but not used), it could be done as such:

```
import os  # noqa: F401

print("Hello, world!")
```

I've published an article with some [noqa examples](https://www.alpharithms.com/noqa-python-501210/) and more elaboration on the above points.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, noqa is ignored!

print('\njson_response =\n' + json.dumps(json_response, indent=4)) # noqa: T201

The output of running the command:

flake8 --toml-config=./pyproject.toml

includes:

.\test_request.py:83:5: T201 print found.
print('\njson_response =\n' + json.dumps(json_response, indent=4))
^

(and T201 is not mentioned in the pyproject.toml file)