# What does "#NOQA" mean inside `__init__.py` file in Chainer library?

Tags: python, chainer

I am reading Chainer source code and noticed at [https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/**init**.py#L7](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/__init__.py#L7)

```
from chainer import configuration  # NOQA
from chainer import cuda  # NOQA
from chainer import dataset  # NOQA
from chainer import datasets  # NOQA
```

What does `#NOQA` mean?

Thanks

Comment: The duplicate target should be changed to [*What does '# noqa' mean in Python comments?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45346575/3357935)

Comment: @doelleri's accepted answer is correct. However, you should note that this is on every single line of `__init__.py` because a linter will complain that these imported names are not being used, since they're not referenced anywhere else in this specific file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`# NOQA` is an instruction for a linter to ignore checks on that line. Flake8/pep8 will not report on errors from lines ending with this. See [the flake8 documentation on ignoring violations](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html) for some more details.