# "Inheriting 'Base', which is not a class" in VS Code using SQLAlchemy declarative_base()

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, sqlalchemy

[image: VS code screenshot]

VS Code shows *"Inheriting 'Base', which is not a class"* as an error message given the below:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Integer , String , Column

Base = declarative_base()

class Socio(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'socios'
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement = True , primary_key = True)
    dni = Column(Integer , unique = True)
    nombre = Column(String(250))
    apellido= Column(String(250))
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't believe everything your linter (or any other static analysis tool for Python) tells you: Run the code and see if/how it **actually** fails (and then include that error message in your question), instead of assuming that VS Code is telling you the truth. `declarative_base()` truly does return a class.

Comment: ...which is to say: What you posted **is not actually an error from Python**. It's a warning from VS Code. Please show us the actual error you get from Python, if any. (A warning won't stop the code from really running; it just says that VS Code's analysis thinks it's likely the code won't run successfully, but that analysis isn't coming from Python itself, and it isn't always right).

Comment: Thank you for your answer . IF i run in a python terminal i get this error :

 nombre = Column(String(250))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Column' is not defined

Comment: Did you include `from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Column` in what you ran in the terminal?

Comment: If i run it in terminal i get no errors now, but when i try to import "Socio" from other .py files i get this error :

"File "/home/gastonpalav/Workspace/frro-soporte-2019-08/practico_05/ejercicio_02.py", line 6, in <module>
    from practico_05.ejercicio_01 import Base , Socio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'practico_05'"

Comment: Please show us how you are using "practico_05".

Comment: That's a completely unrelated error, and should be its own separate question.

Answer (score 10):

#### `Inheriting 'Base', which is not a class` is not actually an error.

Rather, it's a static analysis result coming from Microsoft's Python language server (which in turn leans heavily on [`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org)) for this kind of analysis. It's not always accurate: If a class is dynamically generated and returned by a function (as is the case here), the static-checking tools may not properly understand its type.

As described in [`microsoft/python-language-server#1390`](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1390), this feature can be disabled with the following settings change:

```
"python.analysis.disabled": [
    "inherit-non-class"
],
```

Comment: thank you. I was getting this error with my flask-sqlalchemy models file which this took care of. I have never had a problem with it functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As of VS Code 1.47, when using Marshmallow to serialize/deserialize SQLAlchemy objects and inheriting from [`marshmallow_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema`](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema), using the solution from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222704/2745495):

```
"python.analysis.disabled": [
    "inherit-non-class"
],
```

does not seem to work anymore (i.e. you will still get a "*ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema', which is not a class.*" warning). You can instead use the more generic [`#noqa`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45346575/2745495) comment on specific lines:

```
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):  # noqa
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        sqla_session = db.session
```

Note though, that VS Code treats `#noqa` as a disable-all setting for that line.