# 'Marshmallow' object has no attribute 'ModelSchema'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Everything looks fine from the documentation but it still gives me this error when I'm running the app:

```
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
AttributeError: 'Marshmallow' object has no attribute 'ModelSchema'
```

Everything is imported correctly. The DB is committed. The behavior is the same on pipenv and venv.

Am I missing something?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///marshmallowjson.db'

db  = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))

class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='items')

class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User 
        
class ItemSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Item

@app.route('/')
def index():
    users = User.query.all()
    user_schema = UserSchema(many=True)
    output = user_schema.dump(users).data
    return jsonify({'user': output})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I hate when it happens, but i got the answer immediately after posting...

Was installed only flask-marshmallow, but

```
pipenv install marshmallow-sqlalchemy
```

needed to add to work with SQLAlchemy. Whole code stays the same.

Maybe it will help someone...
Now i got a different issue but that's another story.

Comment: I tried doing this but did not work, same error keeps popping up

Comment: @GKV see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500954/1157536 . ModelSchema was removed from flask-marshmallow. You should migrate to SQLAlchemySchema instead: https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#changelog

Comment: `from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema`

Answer (score 33):

**Conf.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
```

*# flask-marshmallow<0.12.0*

```
class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
      class Meta:
            model = User
```

*# flask-marshmallow>=0.12.0 (recommended)*

```
from conf import ma
class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
      class Meta:
            model = User
            load_instance = True
```

*# flask-marshmallow>=0.12.0 (not recommended)*

```
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema
class UserSchema(ModelSchema):
      class Meta:
            model = User
            sql_session = db.session
```

Comment: `load_instance = True` solved `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.dict' is not mapped` for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On VS Code, using  `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` might show the following warning: "*Inheriting 'ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema', which is not a class.*". It's only a warning, not an error, and has no effect on the program. It can be disabled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222704/2745495.

Comment: `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` has a different `load` method to `ModelSchema` in ways I cannot get my head round. Doesn't return an object and an error any more? e.g. `puppy, errors = puppy_schema.load(request.form)` now chokes

Comment: Shouldn't 2nd case "==" not ">="? I ran the code, https://realpython.com/flask-connexion-rest-api-part-2/, with Flask-Mashmallow 0.12.0, Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy 0.23.0 and Flask_SQLAlchemy 2.0.3.

Answer (score 7):

Cool ! it got deprecated in the newer version .

```
class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
class Meta:
    model = User
```

change that to

```
class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
class Meta:
    model=User
    load_instance=True
```

this should work well now!!

Answer (score 4):

I had marshmallow-sqlalchemy installed, But i still get 'Marshmallow' object has no attribute 'ModelSchema'. For me the following solved the problem.

```
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema

class UserSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Answer (score 4):

From https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-marshmallow/issues/56:

> See
>   https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-marshmallow/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.rst#0120-2020-04-26
>   . It is recommended that you use the newer SQLAlchemySchema rather
>   than ModelSchema.

**Breaking change**: `ma.ModelSchema` and `ma.TableSchema` are removed, since these are deprecated upstream.

Answer (score 3):

Generate marshmallow Schemas from your models using SQLAlchemySchema or SQLAlchemyAutoSchema.  https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from .models import Author

ma = Marshmallow()

class AuthorSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author

    id = ma.auto_field()
    name = ma.auto_field()
    books = ma.auto_field()
```

Answer (score 2):

When a new version was released, it showed this error.
Breaking change: ma.ModelSchema and ma.TableSchema are removed, since these are deprecated upstream.

Please uninstall your current packages and install them with this version.

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-Login==0.5.0
flask-marshmallow==0.9.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
marshmallow==2.20.5
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.18.0
six==1.14.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.13
Werkzeug==1.0.0
WTForms==2.2.1
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for 2 days. Nothing worked, at the end I chagned the version of `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` from `0.23.0` to `0.22.3`

```
pip uninstall marshmallow-sqlalchemy
pip install marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.22.3
```

and the error disappeared.
I hope no one else have to waste their time like I did.

Answer (score 1):

on 2020. it changed to `Schema` instead of `ModelSchema`

check official release note https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Keep good practice in reading the documentation. The solution for you can be this:

```
class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

In my case I have version 14.
So over time, they may change. For this reason, see the documentation:
https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

With the release of Flask-Marshmallow 0.12.0 (2020-04-26), the `ma.ModelSchema` got depreceated.
You should be switching to `ma.SQLAlchemySchema` or `ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema`.

See more at https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id2