Class method implemented in parent class returning the name of the child class
I would like to create a class method, or an abstract method, in a parent class. This method should return the implementer class's name.
For example, using a class method:
class TestParentClass():
    somefield = ""
    
    # create a method to get the name of this class.
    @classmethod
    def get_name(cls):
        class_name = cls.__name__
        return class_name


class TestClass(TestParentClass):
    somefield = TestParentClass.get_name()


print(TestClass().somefield) # I want this to print 'TestClass'

I would like the print statement to print TestClass, but this will print TestParentClass.
I also tried using an abstract method, like so:
class TestParentClass():
    somefield = ""
    
    # create a method to get the name of this class.
    @abstractmethod
    def get_name():
        class_name = __class__.__name__
        print(class_name)
        return class_name

However, also this will print TestParentClass.
Using the constructor in the child class also doesn't do anything different, i.e.:
class TestClass(TestParentClass):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        somefield = TestParentClass.get_name() # still sets 'TestParentClass'

Is there a way to do this in Python?
In other words, I'd like something equivalent to this C# solution:
class TestParentClass
{
    public string SomeField { get; set; }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }
}

class TestClass : TestParentClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        SomeField = this.GetName();
    }
}

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new TestClass().SomeField); // This prints TestClass.
}


You're explicitly calling it on the parent class, before the child class has even finished being created. Try self.somefield = self.get_name(), then cls will be TestClass.

You keep calling TestParentClass.get_name(), which, yes, will always be TestParentClass. You're just calling it in the scope of the child class, but you're not calling the method on the child class.

somefield can be defined by __init_subclass__ (which is special-cased as a class method without needing to decorate it as such).
class TestParentClass:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.somefield = cls.__name__
   

class TestClass(TestParentClass):
    pass


print(TestClass().somefield)


This works amazingly for me.
The only thing to note is that my linter (Pylint in VSCode) doesn't like the somefield declaration inside __init_subclass__(), as it returns: Cannot assign to attribute "somefield" for class "type[TestParentClass]*" Attribute "somefield" is unknown. However, it still works perfectly. I can get around that by setting type: ignore on that line, or by defining a somefield = "" attribute as a first line of TestParentClass.

Yes, that's somewhat of an issue with Pylint (though I don't blame it for not "executing" __init_subclass__ to find out what class attributes will be defined). Another solution is to add somefield: typing.ClassVar[str] to the body of the class, though that somewhat implies that TestParentClass.somefield should exist or be defined somewhere, but  TestParentClass.__init_subclass__ never gets called on TestParentClass itself, only its children.

@alelom you could just use somefield: typing.ClassVar[str]

Why don't you use property instead of a method?
class TestParentClass:

    @property
    def somefield(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__


class TestClass(TestParentClass):
    pass

This should print TestClass when print(TestClass().somefield) is called.
Or if you need on class level:
class classproperty(property): # noqa
    def __get__(self, owner_self, owner_cls): # noqa
        return self.fget(owner_cls) # noqa


class TestParentClass:

    @classproperty
    def somefield(cls):
        class_name = cls.__name__
        return class_name


class TestClass(TestParentClass):
    pass

This would work both for print(TestClass().somefield) and print(TestClass.somefield).

Thank you for this. As you noted, your first solution does work for print(TestClass().somefield), but for print(TestClass.somefield) returns something like <property object at 0x7ff93e6c2b10>. The second solution works for both, but I find it a bit convoluted, would you be able to elaborate on it a bit more, perhaps explaining what noqa means? Thank you in any case.

Those # noqa comments are there to keep the IDE chilled, they don't serve any other function beyond that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45346791/8375783
As for the classproperty, it does what is name tells, it is a property which makes the decorated method to interact with the cls (class blueprint) and not the self (class instance).

As pointed out by the comments, the solution requires that the child class is instantiated when the method is invoked.
A way to do it is to use a class method in the parent class, and also implement a constructor in the parent class that sets the field. For example:
class TestParentClass():
    @classmethod
    def get_name(cls):
        class_name = cls.__name__
        return class_name
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.somefield = self.get_name()

class TestClass(TestParentClass):
    pass

print(TestClass().somefield) # This prints 'TestClass'

