# Python: pyflakes not interpreting noqa comment

Tags: python, pyflakes, pycodestyle

I have something weird going on with `pyflakes` and `noqa` comments.

I have a class similar to the one below (`MyExample`):

- It's the only file in a directory called `pyflakes_f811_test`.
- It only inherits from `abc.ABC`.
- I use `typing.overload` to overload a method within the class.

Invoking pyflakes from the command line messages `redefinition of unused 'enter_yes_no' from line 25`.  Thus, I added in `# noqa: F811` comments, but the messages do not go away.

**My questions**:

- Does anyone know what's going on here?
- Are there any known reasons this can happen?
- Any tips on debugging this?

---

**Source Code**

Name: `pyflakes_f811_overload.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Testing pyflakes F811."""


from abc import ABC
from enum import Enum
from typing import overload, Union


class YesNoOptions(Enum):
    """Enum representing basic states of a yes/no."""

    YES = "YES"
    NO = "NO"


class MyExample(ABC):  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """Example class."""

    # pylint: disable=no-self-use
    @overload
    def enter_yes_no(self, input_: YesNoOptions):
        """Enter yes/no using an enum."""
        ...

    # pylint: disable=no-self-use
    @overload  # noqa: F811
    def enter_yes_no(self, input_: str):
        """Enter yes/no using a string."""
        ...

    def enter_yes_no(self, input_: Union[YesNoOptions, str]):  # noqa: F811
        """Enter yes/no."""
        if isinstance(input_, str):
            parsed_input = input_.upper()
        elif isinstance(input_, YesNoOptions):
            parsed_input = input_.value
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                f"Did not implement yes/no parsing for input {repr(input_)} of "
                f"type {type(input_)}."
            )

        print(f"User entered: {parsed_input}")
```

---

**Reproducing**

`pyflakes` is invoked via the command line as such:

```
(pyflakes_venv) ➜  pyflakes_f811_test pyflakes ./pyflakes_f811_overload.py
./pyflakes_f811_overload.py:28: redefinition of unused 'enter_yes_no' from line 22
./pyflakes_f811_overload.py:33: redefinition of unused 'enter_yes_no' from line 28
```

Package versions:

```
python==3.6.5
pycodestyle==2.4.0
pyflakes==2.1.1
prospector==1.2.0
```

Comment: Reproducing the lint warnings with the code sample, configuration for `.prospector.yml`, and package versions you provided proves unsuccessful. Can you provide a reproducible setup?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I updated the question eliminating `prospector` to make it more reproducible.  Any ideas now, and are you able to reproduce?

Comment: At some point, you may want to consider whether the flexibility provided by such an overloaded function is really worth the effort it takes to make your tools accept it.

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer Are you sure that Pyflakes support `noqa` comments? I cannot find this documented anywhere. You might want to use flake8 instead and check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033727/how-do-i-get-pyflakes-to-ignore-a-statement

Comment: In this case, is it really too much to ask the caller to use `enter_yes_no(YesNoOptions("YES"))`, rather than supporting `enter_yes_no("YES")` directly? Remembering *one* accepted type is a lot easier than remember which `k` types are accepted. ("Can I pass `True` directly, or do I have to convert that to `"YES"` or `YesNoOptions.YES` first?")

Comment: @NelsonYeung yes according to this comment, it seems to have been done: https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/issues/320#issuecomment-365299137, I may be wrong though

Comment: @chepner the sample code I have here is just a sample, with all dependencies abstracted away.  My actual use case is different, and would have over-complicated this question.  And per having an overloaded method, I think it's reasonable, when the tradeoff should be just adding `# noqa` comments.  Just in this particular use case, it's causing me problems :/

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer It sounds like he's using flake8, to be honest. There're a few mentions of flake8 in that issue. Since flake8 is a wrapper around Pyflakes, people would still log problems to Pyflakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyflakes does not support the `noqa` comments for ignoring specific lines. You can check in their source code https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes that there is not a mention of `noqa`. The `noqa` feature is only in [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html). Since flake8 uses Pyflakes I suggest you switch to flake8:

```
pip install flake8
flake8 ./pyflakes_f811_overload.py
```

For your particular problem of the `@overload` decorator, although it has been fixed in the master branch ([#435](https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/pull/435)), it has not been released yet (as of 02/April/2020).

Comment: Agrees with this: https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/issues/431#issuecomment-465638882